# How do I wipe a hard disk completely using a Live CD?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am brand new to this and just need to completely wipe the hdd for a fresh Ubuntu install. The live cd is mounted and I'm in the terminal window. 'wipe' did not work but gparted seems to be there. the 'gparted' install command shows, 'gparted is already the newest version (0.25.0-1).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You don't need to wipe your disk to install, most options (not all) will create necessary partitions & install Ubuntu.  You don't need to use `gparted`.  Telling us the release of Ubuntu you are trying to install also makes it easier to advise you in less general terms.

Comment: I have install media on the system besides me, and it offers to "Erase Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and re-install" or "Install Xubuntu 19.04 alongisde .." and more options.  You want the first option (where instead of seeing Ubuntu 18.04.2 that my system has, it'll say whatever was on your system most likely.

Comment: Please change your question, so that it is understandable what you are asking!

Comment: You mention that "The live cd is mounted". Fine. Then you have to reboot on Live CD, you cannot boot on your HDD if you wish to install something on it. Once booted on live CD, you will see an icon to install Ubuntu. Click on it, follow the instructions. At a specific step, as @guiverc says, you will have the option to erase you former system and install your new one on the full hard drive. But be 100% sure that it's what you wish! It will not be recoverable if you accidentally deleted partitions that you wanted to keep!...

Answer (score 2):

Wipe and gparted are separate programs. You can install wipe using this command.

```
sudo apt install wipe
```

If you don't have internet you can do it manually using dd.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=100M
```

instead of /dev/sda type your hard drive file which is in this format:

```
/dev/sdx
```

and specify bs according to your ram.

Comment: errrr... the user clearly is new and means "format" by "wipe" not "get rid or incriminating data"

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Format" or "remove all partitions" or "Format to unpartitioned" or anything of the sort.

Live CDs come prepacked with Gparted.

Open the start menu and type "gp", "Gparted" will show up, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on it and using that tool you'll be able to easily format or do whatever other disk operations you want to do.

for example :

Once you've selected the right drive with the drop down menu (by defaul the usb will be last in the list or not show up, so do not worry about that)

then "Partition" -> "Create partition table"
[image: create partition table]

Remember you click the chack mark "apply" otherwise it does not apply.

this will give you a clean slate.

That being said if the whole point of this is to install ubuntu afterwards this is pointless. you can just start installing ubuntu straight away and when you get to the choice of install type (side by side, replace,re-install) just choose "something else" it opens up what is basically gparted but a version of gparted that is focused to creating the right partitions for booting ubuntu.

You'll need a 500Mb EFI partion first and the rest as an ext4 partion where `/` is mounted the rest of the paramaters should just remain defaults.

With such a setup, conditions for installing will be met and the installer will allow you to proceed. It works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disks by pressing the Dash button (or in the apps button, bottom left, on 18.04+) and typing it in. You can select the proper disk, and then press the menu button on that disk in the top right of the window. Click format, and then select "Overwrite (Slow)" and format. BE CAREFUL with formatting drives, especially securely, as you cannot recover the data afterwards and you need to be extra certain you've selected the correct one. If it's not impossible, I'd even go so far as to shut down, unplug important non-targeted drives and then start up, so I couldn't accidentally or otherwise delete data from them. Of course, just double checking should work too ;)