# External Hard Drive neither recognized nor possible to format it

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I wanted to encrypt my external hard drive. With "Disks" I chose "Format Partition". Because I had around 500GB of data on it, I let it run over the night. But that morning, it still didn't finish. So in my impatientness, I just unplugged the external hard drive and the I deleted all the partitions on it. Now, I'm left with one partition (Free Space - 1GB) and I can't chose "Format Partition" anymore, nor does the external hard drive show up in nautilus...

Can anyone help me solving the problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I think I need to reset the external hard drive comlpetely. If I want to create a new partition on it it says: "Error on creating partition on /dev/sdb: Failed to meet partition size on device '/dev/sdb' (usdisks-error-quark, 0)"

Comment: You can try [zeroing the drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/17658/253251), see if it help. I once restored a usb flash drive I found on garbage can using `dd`.

Comment: try re-creating the partition table. I just made a similar answer :  https://askubuntu.com/a/1128785/307184 , tell me if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Emmet, zeroing the drive worked for me!